# How to calculate the charuco imgPoints without using cv2.aruco.getBoardsObjectAndImagePoins()

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, aruco

How to calculate the charuco imgPoints without using [getBoardsObjectAndImagePoins()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#ga0c158c55c50df8354930927d819f7e9d)

I try to find the charuco imgPoins. This function give me for the same input parameters every time different imgPoins.

Thanks!

Comment: you know the bug was already reported. what is the question?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz any idea how to calculate the imgPoints for the `stereoCalibrate function` [Link] 
(https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga91018d80e2a93ade37539f01e6f07de5) ?

Comment: is that a separate question? have you googled it? please take the [tour] and review [ask] and other articles in the [help]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz a no frills question